# How to supress windowed aggregation result in Spring Cloud Kafka Streams?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am using Kafka-streams-binder in my Spring Cloud project. The Kafka stream application uses sliding window of 6 minutes to aggregate the results and analyze patter. But the problem is that the aggregation operation is generating duplicate results.

I want to suppress the intermediate results and publish only after the window ends in the application. **This can be achieved by Kafka .supress() operation in Kafka 2.1.1**. But the Spring Cloud version does not have the latest kafka to use the capability.

**Dependencies used by Project**

> ```
> <spring-boot.version>2.1.9.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
> <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
> ```

Any alternatives for **suppressing the intermediate results** would be helpful.

Comment: If one of the answers below addressed your question, please mark it as Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

> Any alternatives for suppressing the intermediate results would be helpful.

There is no equivalent functionality available in prior versions of Kafka Streams that give you the same behavior as the [recently introduced Suppress feature](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-streams-take-on-watermarks-and-triggers/).

The closest you can get is to [configure your Kafka Streams application](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html)'s record caches (settings like `cache.max.bytes.buffering`) and the `commit.interval.ms` to *reduce* the number of "intermediate" updates you will be seeing.  But this will not fully remove any such updates unlike the new Suppress feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the kafka-clients and kafka-streams versions, as described in the [appendix to the Spring for Apache Kafka](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.11.RELEASE/reference/html/#deps-for-21x) reference manual.

If you are not using the embedded kafka broker in tests, you just need to override the kafka clients and streams.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Isn't it considered as an anti-pattern from spring boot side?

Comment: In general, yes, but Kafka has a more frequent release cadence than Boot so we (Spring for Apache Kafka) do our best to maintain compatibility unless there are breaking APIs. IIRC, I don't think you can go to 2.2.x or higher with Boot 2.1 but you should be ok with 2.1.1. On the other hand, you could upgrade to Boot 2.2.x, and `Hoxton.RELEASE` to get the latest and greatest (kafka 2.3).